# Raising a power series by a power series?

Tags: power-series

I know addition and multiplication are well defined operations on formal power series. Now say you have two formal power series $F(x),G(x)\in R[[x]]$, with $R\supset\mathbb{Q}$ is the coefficient ring.

Is there a way to define $F(x)^{G(x)}$? Is there a standard well defined definition for this operation that hopefully satisfies the usual exponent laws? Thanks.

Comment: No, even $x^x$ doesn't make sense in the power series ring !

Comment: At least, $F(x)$ probably needs to have a nonzero constant term, since otherwise you expect something like a logarithmic singularity (think of the expression as $\exp(G(x)\ln F(x))$). But then, I would suspect (but don't know) that this standard formula will provide a positive answer.

Comment: It interesting to note that $${\left( {1 + x + \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2!}} + \frac{{{x^3}}}{{3!}} +  \cdots } \right)^x} = 1 + x^2 + \frac{{{{\left( {{x^2}} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}} + \frac{{{{\left( {{x^2}} \right)}^3}}}{{3!}} +  \cdots $$
i.e $(e^x)^x = e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Composition of formal power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series) can be done via the [power-series version of Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version).  In that way one can find the series for $\log_e F(x)$.  Then one can say
$$
F(x)^{G(x)} = e^{G(x)\log_e F(x)}.
$$
Multiplication of formal power series is a well-known operation.  Exponentiation can be done via the [exponential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula).

Comment: Provided $F(x)$ has a nonzero constant term.